# Biopython | Why do I only get e values of 0.0?

Tags: python-3.x, biopython, blast, ncbi

I am looking to get the 5 best alignment results from blast to the 16S rRNA sequence which I fetched from with the Entrez module. However, when I analyze my alignments, all my e-value scores which I get from `record.alignment.hsp.expect` are exactly 0.0.

Just by eyeballing the alignments, the sequences were not 100% the same.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio import Entrez
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML

Entrez.email = "obsto123@gmail.com"
handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide",id="NC_000913.1",rettype="gb",retmode="text")
seq_record = SeqIO.read(handle,"genbank")

records = []
for feature in seq_record.features:
    if feature.type == "rRNA" and "16S" in feature.qualifiers["product"][0]:
        records.append(seq_record.seq[feature.location.start.position:feature.location.end.position])
rRNA = records[0]

print("Now doing blast search...")

blast_data = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn","nt",records[0])

with open("blast_xml.xml","w") as f:
    f.write(blast_data.read())
xml = open("blast_xml.xml","r")
blast_record = NCBIXML.read(xml)
    
for alignment in blast_record.alignments:
    for hsp in alignment.hsps:
        print(hsp.expect)
```

Comment: where does blast_xml comes from ?

Comment: I am sorry, I mistakenly posted the wrong script. I just added the right script.
Thank you for your reply!

Comment: https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?CMD=Web&PAGE_TYPE=BlastDocs&DOC_TYPE=FAQ#expect  Q: What is the Expect (E) value?
The Expect value (E) is a parameter that describes the number of hits one can "expect" to see by chance when searching a database of a particular size. It decreases exponentially as the Score (S) of the match increases. Essentially, the E value describes the random background noise. For example, an E value of 1 assigned to a hit can be interpreted as meaning that in a database of the current size one might expect to see 1 match with a similar score simply by chance

Comment: The lower the E-value, or the closer it is to zero, the more "significant" the match is. However, keep in mind that virtually identical short alignments have relatively high E values. This is because the calculation of the E value takes into account the length of the query sequence. These high E values make sense because shorter sequences have a higher probability of occurring in the database purely by chance. For more details please see the calculations in the BLAST Course.

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/BLAST/tutorial/Altschul-1.html

Comment: Okay, so there is no mistake in my code. I guess that the e-value is then probably rounded down by python to exactly 0.

Comment: Not sure aboit that have a look at xml file and see what is there

Comment: you could also use `feature.extract(seq_record.seq)` instead of `seq_record.seq[feature.location.start.position:feature.location.end.position]`.